# Footnoterule in reledpar with ledgroups

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

I'm using reledpar (wonderful!) to typeset texts in parallel columns. I'm using ledgroups so I can put footnotes directly below each column.

Footnotes in the right column are putting a \footnoterule on the left side of the page. If I have footnotes in each column, there are two rules, stacked on top of each other.

Question: How can I just get rid of the rules altogether? Redefining \footnoterule seems to do nothing.

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[parledgroup]{reledpar}

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alph{footnoteB}}% <-- differentiating leftside notes from right side notes. For some reason, using \footnoteA on the left side steps the count of \footnoteA on the right side, which I can’t allow!

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}% <-- Trying to get rid of footnote rules

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
Some left column text, with a footnote.\footnoteA{Left side footnote.}
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
Some right column text that is rather longer and has a footnote.\footnoteB{Why does the rule not appear above this note?}
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}` before loading reledmac.

However, that is a bug of reledpar. You should not have two footnote rule. Please open an issue on github (if I remember well, there is an other bug with parallel ledgroup).